# Exhibiting the distinct cosets of a cyclic subgroup H in group G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be the group U(24) and H the cyclic subgroup generated by the element 7.

Exhibit all of the distinct cosets of H in G.

I am coming up with this.
(I created the Cayley table for U(24) - using the elements 1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23.)

<1> = {1}
<5> = (5*5 = 1)  {5}
<7> = (7*7 = 1)  {7}

and so forth since each element times itself is equal to the identity.

Is this correct? there are 8 elements and therefore 8 distinct cosets for U(24).

---

Next piece of the problem I'm working thru.

Why is H a normal subgroup of G?

I am not quite sure what H is... exactly to compare

I'm guessing <7> = H

so by looking at the left and right cosets

<1>H  <->  H<1>
<5>H (5*7 = 11) <-> H<5> (7*5 = 11)
<7>H (7*7 = 1) <-> H<7> (7*7 = 1)

and then I would stop there and say it was normal subgroup of G.
with order 1 and the index of H in G is 2?

But Lagrange Theorem states the order of G = (order of H)* index of H in G... this doesn't end up working in this case (Makes me wonder if I am doing this part wrong)

---

Exhibit distinct elements of the quotient group of G/H... (So I can construct a Cayley Table for G/H.)

I am just starting to work on this... some help to get me started would be nice :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The group $H$ has two elements $\{7, 1\}$ and therefore its index in $G$ is 4. Also note that right cosets coincide with left cosects so that $gH = Hg$ (this comes from the fact that G is abelian and also answers your second question). So e.g. $5 \{7, 1\} = \{11, 5\} = 11 \{7, 1\}$. You'll get 4 cosets like this.

Third question is really the same thing as the first question (thanks to $H$ being normal).

Comment: So the Cayley Table for the third part is really the same as the U(24) table OR am I using the 4 cosets as the elements in the table? I have a feeling it is taking 1H, 5H, 13H and 17H and building a Cayley table with those distinct elements.

Comment: I see now that order G = 8, order H = 2 and the index of H in G is now 4 --- so that does work itself out.

Comment: Back to first comment... trying to work that part out. 1H being the identity, all distinct elements times itself gives 1H, but then for example what would 5H*13H become? (11,5)*(19,13) = (19,13,11,5)  that result is not 1H,5H,13H or 17H.

Comment: How would I describe this group which is isomorphic to G/H and thus being a nontrivial homomorphic image of U(24)? Using in the description one of the following: cyclic order of..., non-cyclic abelian of order..., or nor-abelian of order...? Not sure what this is asking and how I can answer it.

Comment: Ad third comment: recall that group operation on G/H is defined as aH * bH = (a*b)H (this is well-defined precisely because H is normal). E.g. 5H * 13 H = (5*13)H = 17H.

Comment: Ad fourth comment: well, there are various groups with these properties. Consider group of integers mod n with addition mod n. This is cyclic (and therefore abelian). Then there are non-cyclic abelian groups (e.g. symmetry group of rectangle) and then there are non-abelian groups (consider the group of permutation of set with n elements, n > 2). You are asked to examine the group structure of G/H and determine which of the said properties it has. It is clearly abelian (because G is). Try to find out whether it is also a cyclic group (i.e. you can find g in G/H such that g generates whole G/H).